# What version of twitter bootstrap is supported by the twitter-bootstrap gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

http://rubygems.org/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails

The current version of twitter-bootstrap gem is 2.2.6, how would I find the twitter bootstrap version which is supported by this gem. The twitter bootstrap version which is available for download from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ is v2.3.1.

Is there a correlation between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the changelog](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#changelog), it uses Twitter Bootstrap version 2.3.1.

There is no apparent relation between the version number of the gem and the version of Twitter Bootstrap:

```
...
Released gem v.2.1.5 (minor fixes, install generator detects javascript template engine, updated to Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.1)
Released gem v.2.1.6 (minor fixes)
Added static stylesheets support
Released gem v.2.1.8 and updated to Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.2
Released gem v.2.1.9
Released gem v.2.2.0 (Font Awesome 3)
Released gem v.2.2.1 (minor fixes and updates)
Released gem v.2.2.2 (Bootstrap 2.3.0)
...
Released gem v.2.2.5 (Bootstrap 2.3.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem is [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) - although it uses SASS instead of LESS, it does track bootstrap versions with its own version numbers (see the note on Versioning in the README.md).

bootstrap-sass also uses version 2.3.1 currently.